# Links are showing blocked content when insert excel in current context using insertWorksheetsFromBase64

Tags: javascript, excel, office365, office-js, excel-addins

Currently I have created one excel Addin in which I am selecting one template excel in file upload  and  using insertWorksheetsFromBase64 method to import all sheets from template to current workbook.

```
    let myFile = document.getElementById("file");
    let reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (event) => {
        Excel.run((context) => {
            // Remove the metadata before the base64-encoded string.
            let startIndex = reader.result.toString().indexOf("base64,");
            let externalWorkbook = reader.result.toString().substr(startIndex + 7);
                
            // Retrieve the current workbook.
            let workbook = context.workbook;
                
            // Set up the insert options. 
            let options = { 
                sheetNamesToInsert: [], // Insert all the worksheets from the source workbook.
                positionType: Excel.WorksheetPositionType.after, // Insert after the `relativeTo` sheet.
                relativeTo: "Sheet1" // The sheet relative to which the other worksheets will be inserted. Used with `positionType`.
            }; 
                
             // Insert the new worksheets into the current workbook.
             workbook.insertWorksheetsFromBase64(externalWorkbook, options);
             return context.sync();
        });
    };
    
    // Read the file as a data URL so we can parse the base64-encoded string.
    reader.readAsDataURL(myFile.files[0]);
```

But after this all cell links in inserted sheets showing blocked content like shown in image
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mq7k.png)

As per my understanding it is not updating cell reference as per current excel. Can someone please help how can i update reference as well.

**Update**
After clicking on continue get below error

[Error aftr continue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pxEo.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is by design(it is a security warning), when you upload the workbook which contains the external cell reference, and then open the workbook in excel online, you will also see the same message. You could just click the "Enable content" to continue.

Comment: I tried same as well, but after that i got error again like "Unable to refresh : We couldn't get updated values from a linked workbook". I have added screenshot as well in question in update section

Comment: Is it possible to do it via code as we don't want user to click every time we open any excel online with some linked cells

Comment: It's by design, as XLO doesn't totally support this feature. It's hard for XLO to read information from some another workbook currently, for example, if you are on OneDrive, and there is a reference link to another workbook locally, it can't support, if there is a reference link to another cell on different account, can't support, if there is a reference link to another folder that you doesn't have permission, can't support yet.....